# NextJS and Kubernetes - router.push is sending the request to another POD instead of using the same

Tags: kubernetes, redirect, next.js, next-router

I have a NextJS app deployed on a Kubernetes Cluster. My app handles redirects (Same website, different path) based on business logic and i was wondering if there is a possibility to handle that "redirect" (im using router.push from useRouter) in the same pod.

What happens is that when the first request comes in, POD#1 handle it, when a redirect is detected, then the logic fires router.push and that redirect its been handled by POD#2.

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to configure on your load balancer "sticky sessions" to make sure requests from a client goes to the same node.

And then using anti-affinity rules, make sure you don't deploy more than 1 pod of your app per node

Anyway, make sure your requests are stateless as possible, except for some caching optimisation it shouldn't matter which pod the request hits.

### Documentation references

- [Digital Ocean documentation on how they do sticky sessions](https://docs.digitalocean.com/glossary/sticky-session/)
- [Assign pods to nodes with anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity)